# Matching model to ForeignKey based on Foreign Model's date range

Tags: python, sql, django

Say I have two models.

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s (%s) -> (%s)' % (self.name,self.start_date,self.end_date)



class ModelB(models.Model):
    modelA = models.ForeignKey(ModelA,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    date = models.DateField('Date submitted',auto_now_add=True)
```

Given say, 10 ModelA objects, with varying date ranges, how would you match ModelB to a ModelA on form submission based on ModelB's date?

Edit: For the sake of this question,let's assume that we know that ModelA date fields will not overlap.

Comment: What if there are *multiple* `ModelA`s that all have an interval that contains the given `date`?